# Использование std::wstringstream

Tags: c++

Мне нужно записать в const wchar_t* items следущее

```
Vector(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)
```

Записано оно у меня в векторе vertexBuffer.
Например

```
vertexBuffer[0] - Vector(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)
vertexBuffer[1] - Vector(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f)
```

и т.д
И мне нужно чтобы оно записало 3 координаты и запятую между ними.
Мне нужно чтобы такое было на выходе

```
 const wchar_t *items[] = { L"Vector(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)", L"Vector(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f" и т.д все с вектора };
```

но я не знаю как такое реализовать через std::wstringstream. Буду рад помощи

Как я  сделал но  код не хочет работать:
UPD(кричит  на последнюю строчку коду в втором форе):

```
sstd::vector<std::wstring> wstring(10);
const wchar_t* items = new wchar_t[10];
for (decltype(vertexBuffer.size()) index = 0; index < vertexBuffer.size(); ++index)
{
    std::wstringstream ws;
    ws << L"Vetrex(" << vertexBuffer[index].mX << L"," << vertexBuffer[index].mY << L"," << vertexBuffer[index].mZ << L" )";
    wstring[index] = ws.str();
}
for (decltype(wstring.size()) index = 0; index < wstring.size(); ++index)
{
    items[index] = (const wchar_t*)wstring[index].c_str();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас в последнем примере навран тип массива `items`. Он объявлен как `const wchar_t* items`, а это одна строка, не массив строк как в начале вопроса.

Вы нигде не пытаетесь выделить сами строки. Массив выделяется, но его элементы нет. Массив ссылается на строки внутри объектов типа `wstring`. Это можно заставить работать, но вам потребуется хранить массив и вектор вместе, массив без вектора - куча висящих указателей.

Нормальный дизайн может выглядеть так: по вершине выделяем одну строку и заполняем её символами:

```
wchar_t *dump(const Vertex &vertex) {
    std::wstringstream wss;
    wss << L"Vertex(" << vertex.mX << L", " << vertex.mY << L", " << vertex.mZ
        << L")";
    const std::wstring ws = wss.str();
    const auto n = ws.size() + 1;
    const wchar_t *chars = ws.c_str();
    wchar_t *copy = new wchar_t[n];
    std::copy(chars, chars + n, copy);
    return copy;
}
```

По вектору вершин выделяем массив строк и заполняем их:

```
const wchar_t **dump(const std::vector<Vertex> &vertices) {
    const auto n = vertices.size();
    const wchar_t **items = new const wchar_t*[n];
    for (auto i = decltype(n){0}; i < n; ++i) {
        items[i] = dump(vertices[i]);
    }
    return items;
}
```

Тестируем:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<Vertex> vertexBuffer{
        Vertex(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
        Vertex(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f)
    }; 
    const wchar_t **items = dump(vertexBuffer);
    const auto n = vertexBuffer.size();
    for (auto i = decltype(n){0}; i < n; ++i) {
        std::wcout << items[i] << L'\n';
    }
}
```

> ```
> $ g++ -std=c++17 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror vertices.cpp && ./a.out 
> Vertex(1, 0, 0)
> Vertex(0.5, 0.5, 0)
> ```

**P.S.** Не забудьте удалить массив после использования.

**P.P.S.** Размер массива нужно везде носить вместе с массивом - странный дизайн.

Answer (score 0):

```
ws.str();
```

возращает временный объект **std::wstring**. Обязательно нужно зафиксировать это переменной

```
std::wstring res(ws.str());
```

Затем из этой строки выклянчить копию с помощью **wcscpy**

```
#include<sstream>
wchar_t * wcopy( new wchar_t[res.size()+1UL]);
wcscpy(wcopy,res.c_str());
```

Comment: AlexGlebe, а мануал почитать? Не ? "std::stringstream::str returns a string object with a copy of the current contents of the stream".

Comment: JaponDemon, вы можете свой ответ выложить как альтернативу.